# Use CTRL + Arrow to skip full symbol in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

In the previous versions of Visual Studio, I could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> to move between whole symbols, i.e., jump between whitespace:

> Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> when my cursor is:
>
> ```
> void int GetMyInteger|();
> ```
>
> Would result in the state:
>
> ```
> void int |GetMyInteger();
> ```

Now, in **Visual Studio 2012**, the behavior has been modified to something like this:

> Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> when my cursor is:
>
> ```
> void int GetMyInteger|();
> ```
>
> Would result in the state:
>
> ```
> void int GetMy|Integer();
> ```

I want the older behavior back, as it was more efficient to navigate the code. Is there any configuration that would allow me to change it back?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.  What addins do you have installed?

Comment: @SLaks, yeah, completely forgot to mention, I got Resharper installed. Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: Yes.  Explore its settings.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In my Resharper 7, this can be turned off in the following way.

Resharper/Options

=> Environment/Editor

Find the checkbox for "Use CamelHumps". Uncheck it

VERY annoying feature to have turned on by default. Such a relief to turn it off, since I do almost all code navigation with my keyboard.

Comment: Thanks! I had found it a while back but forgot to post. For that, you deserve a nice accept. And you are completely right - who decided to activate that by default? (I'd ask who'd want that in the first place as well).

Comment: So without Resharper, this is not possible?

Comment: Thank god for that... was also annoying me for ages!